# Get Webhook if donation is made to 3rd Party Charity through my Website

Tags: paypal, sprite, payment, donations

I would like to offer a service to my website's users if they donate to a charity while visiting my website. E.g.: Users visit my website and can unlock something if they click a button to donate $10 to a suggested animal sanctuary charity.

I would like to be able to keep track who donated. Importantly, I am looking for a way where I don't have to handle any money. I just want the money to go directly to the charity and get informed how much was donated by the users visiting my website.

Current solutions seem to suggest that PayPal is the best way to do this. Are there other alternatives also, preferably alternatives that have an API for this very purpose and offer **Webhooks**??

The best alternative I could come up with so far is to create a GoFundMe, but I would much prefer if it is donated directly to a chartiy. Does anybody have an idea how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the PayPal Donation flow, you can [use the Donate SDK or button](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/donate/), setting a `business` parameter (rather than a hosted_button_id) to a value that is the PayPal account to receive the donation.

For notification you can use the old IPN service, specifying a `notify_url` as [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/).

---

The newer Webhooks service cannot be paired with facilitating Donate flow payments to another account.

Comment: I just tried it and everything worked just like you said. Much appreciated! Helped me out a lot! : )
Furthermore, what to do is demosntrated in this video which was also really helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFUdd3gveN8